# Why does Clarence need space to plant a transmitter on somebody?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-8

In *Oceans Eight (2018)*, Debbie and her team, who are about to steal a necklace from Daphne’s neck at the Met museum, are discussing the robbing plan:

> Lou: And once we get the Toussaint, we are gonna have to get it out of
>   there without being detected, and they're gonna go over their security
>   footage with a fine-tooth comb, and anyone seen exiting that bathroom
>   is gonna be a suspect.
>
> Debbie: So...So we get a mule. Somebody else is gonna move it for us.
>   **How much space do you need outside that bathroom to plant it on
>   somebody?**
>
> Clarence: I don't know. Nine feet?

Why does Clarence need space to plant a transmitter on somebody?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They weren't planting a transmitter on someone.

> DEBBIE: And how long is it gonna take us to build
>   a nine-foot blind spot?
>
> 9 BALL: Moving a camera?
>
> DEBBIE: Mmm-hmm.
>
> 9 BALL: Bit by bit, 10, 12 days.

They planted the necklace on a busboy's tray who then unknowingly passed it on to Amita. They needed a nine foot blind spot in the security camera coverage so the security camera couldn't see this happen.